Web3 dApp - swapExactTokensForEth issue
Please help me sort this out, I'll give you a gift.
My dApp is built with NextJS, Typescript, TailwindCSS.(imports
When you select the buy button on my dApp, it prepares swapExactEthforTokens and it works perfectly fine .The transaction goes trough, all good. buy
However when you switch to the SELL button, it should prepare swapExactTokensForEth and by confirming the button it should trigger swapExactTokensForEth. Unfortunately the transaction cannot be triggered (please see attached image)sell
I attached the code from my page.tsx two constants linked to the swapping section of my dApp.
  const handleApproval = async () => {
    try {
      if (isClient) {
        const provider = new Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const tokenContract = new Contract(
          tokenAddress,
          ['function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)'],
          signer
        );
  
        const uniswap = new Contract(
          '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D',
          [
            'function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
            'function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
          ],
          signer
        );
  
        const approvalAmount = MaxUint256;
        const approvalResponse = await tokenContract.approve(uniswap.address, approvalAmount);
        await approvalResponse.wait();
        console.log('Token spend approved.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Approval Error:', error);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setTransactionMessage('Approval Failed. Please try again.');
    }
  };
  

  const handleTransaction = async () => {
    if (!isConnected) {
      setTransactionMessage('Please Connect Your Wallet');
      return;
    }
  
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setTransactionMessage('');
      setQuoteText(''); // Clear the previous quote
  
      if (isClient) {
        const provider = new Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const userAddress = await signer.getAddress();
        const userBalance = await provider.getBalance(userAddress);
  
        if (action === 'buy' && userBalance.lt(parseEther(amount))) {
          setTransactionMessage('You don\'t have enough ETH.');
          setIsLoading(false);
          return;
        }

        const validateSlippageTolerance = (slippageTolerance: string): Percent => {
          const value = parseFloat(slippageTolerance);
          if (isNaN(value) || value < 0.1 || value > 5) {
            console.warn('Invalid slippage tolerance value. Using default value of 0.5%.');
            return new Percent('5', '1000'); // Default to 0.5%
          }
          return new Percent(`${Math.floor(value * 100)}`, '10000');
        };
  
        const token = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(ChainId.MAINNET, tokenAddress, provider);
        const weth = WETH[ChainId.MAINNET];
        const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(token, weth, provider);
        const route = new Route([pair], action === 'buy' ? weth : token);
  
        let trade;
        let outputAmount;
  
        if (action === 'buy') {
          const amountIn = ethers.parseEther(amount);
          trade = new Trade(route, new TokenAmount(weth, amountIn), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);
          outputAmount = trade.outputAmount.toFixed(token.decimals);
          setQuoteText(`You will receive ${outputAmount} ${token.symbol}`);
        } else {
          const tokenContract = new Contract(
            token.address,
            ['function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)'],
            provider
          );
          const tokenAmountBN = await tokenContract.balanceOf(userAddress);
          const tokenAmount = parseFloat(formatUnits(tokenAmountBN.toString(), token.decimals));
          const amountOut = parseUnits(amount, token.decimals);
  
          if (tokenAmount < parseFloat(amount)) {
            setTransactionMessage('You don\'t have enough tokens to sell.');
            setIsLoading(false);
            return;
          }
  
          trade = new Trade(route, new TokenAmount(token, amountOut.toString()), TradeType.EXACT_OUTPUT);
          outputAmount = trade.inputAmount.toFixed(weth.decimals);
          setQuoteText(`You will receive ${outputAmount} ETH`);
        }
  
        const slippageToleranceValue = validateSlippageTolerance(slippageTolerance);
        const amountOutMin = trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageToleranceValue).raw;
        const path = action === 'buy' ? [weth.address, token.address] : [token.address, weth.address];
        const to = userAddress;
        const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + transactionDeadline * 60;
        const value = action === 'buy' ? trade.inputAmount.raw : '0';
  
        const uniswap = new Contract(
          '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D',
          [
            'function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
            'function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
          ],
          signer
        );
  
        let transactionResponse;
        if (action === 'buy') {
          transactionResponse = await uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens(
            amountOutMin.toString(),
            path,
            to,
            deadline,
            { value: value.toString() }
          );
        } else {
          const tokenContract = new Contract(
            token.address,
            ['function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256)'],
            provider
          );
  
          const allowance = await tokenContract.allowance(userAddress, uniswap.address);
          if (allowance.lt(trade.inputAmount.raw)) {
            console.log('Approving token spend...');
            await handleApproval();
          }
  
          console.log('Swapping tokens to ETH...');
          transactionResponse = await uniswap.swapExactTokensForETH(
            trade.inputAmount.raw.toString(),
            amountOutMin.toString(),
            path,
            to,
            deadline
          );
        }
  
        setTransactionMessage('Transaction Pending...');
        const receipt = await transactionResponse.wait();
        setTransactionMessage('Transaction Confirmed.');
  
        console.log('Transaction Hash:', receipt.transactionHash);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Transaction Error:', error);
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        if ('code' in error) {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          if (errorCode === 4001) {
            setTransactionMessage('Transaction Rejected by User');
          } else if (errorCode === -32603) {
            setTransactionMessage('Insufficient Funds for Transaction');
          } else {
            setTransactionMessage(`Transaction Failed. Error Code: ${errorCode}, Error Message: ${error.message}`);
          }
        } else {
          setTransactionMessage(`Transaction Failed. Error: ${error.message}`);
        }
      } else {
        setTransactionMessage('Transaction Failed. Please try again.');
      }
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

I tried different approaches, slippage tolerance, different amounts, different tokens. Nothing worked
